# Issues with the ADAPTS- R package

Tags: r, deconvolution

I'm using the function `buildSeed()` below:

```r
library(ADAPTS)
ct1 <- runif(1000, 0, 100)
ct2 <- runif(1000, 0, 100)
dataMat <- cbind(ct1, ct1, ct1, ct1, ct1, ct1, ct2, ct2, ct2, ct2)
rownames(dataMat) <- make.names(rep('gene', nrow(dataMat)), unique=TRUE)
noise <- matrix(runif(nrow(dataMat)*ncol(dataMat), -2, 2), nrow = nrow(dataMat), byrow = TRUE)
dataMat <- dataMat + noise
newSigMat <- buildSeed(trainSet=dataMat)
```

I get error:

```
Error in buildSeed(trainSet = dataMat) : 
  could not find function "buildSeed"
```

Here is the data I am trying to work with:

```r
dim(expr_mat)
> [1] 9978  237

head(expr_mat)
> mo_ctr_dmso_0_5h_d2_t1 mo_ctr_dmso_0_5h_d3_t1 mo_ctr_dmso_1h_d1_t1 mo_ctr_dmso_1h_d2_t2 mo_ctr_dmso_1h_d2_t1
RP11-459I19.1            9.244510e-01           2.912490e-01         2.495870e+00         8.486300e-01         1.963290e+00
RP13-270P17.3            2.259280e+00           5.893050e-01         3.720860e+00         2.969720e+00         4.102030e+00
RP11-574K11.31           1.906047e+00           1.390515e-01         1.458889e+00         6.886160e-01         1.053803e+00
RP11-212I21.5            4.394590e+00           7.547210e-02         5.057090e+00         5.420640e-01         3.694030e+00
```

Comment: FYI your code sample runs fine and does generate a figure for me.

Answer (score 0):

It works with R 4.0.2. Thanks everyone!